# How do I explicitly install and launch the 64-bit version of Python after installing the Python.org distribution?

Tags: python, numpy

I just installed the latest version of Python from [enter link description here](http://www.Python.org).  I expected the installer to query my CPU at installion time and install the a 64-bit version by default, since my CPU machine is 64-bit Intel version.

After installation, I am a unclear by the version data that shows in IDLE when I start Python:

`Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

I want to use highest performance Python for machine learning, database, and number crunching applications.

There is no "64-bit only" version on Python.org website.   The only kit available is named `Windows x86-64 executable installer Windows for AMD64/EM64T/x64.`

Does the Python installer install both the 32-bit and 64-bit API?  This is not reflected in the version information that is displayed.

Am I asking the wrong question, because the 64-bit and 32-bit APIs are both installed, and just the version displayed is not complete? How does Windows or Python know to switch to the 64-bit API for libraries like Numpy, Numba, etc. that work best with 64-bit code?

Is there a way to explicitly start the 64-bit version?

When should I do this explicitly versus letting Windows launch the default 32-bit version?

Answer (score 0):

you should only download and install the Windows x86-64 executable installer Windows for AMD64/EM64T/x64. if you want 64bit. However do NOT expect python to be super fast, as a dynamic typing language, it will be at least 100 times slower than static typing language such as C/C++ or Java.

If you want your numpy/pandas/sklearn to be as fast as possible, you should focus on optimizing your workflow, don't commit to unnecessary task. Or you can check out intel's python distribution if you're on Intel CPU. Or explore other multi-process pandas solution when on a multi-core AMD cpu.

Comment: Actually, I was searching the web for the term AMD64 and found the following: "AMD64 is designed to enable simultaneous 32- and 64-bit computing with no degradation in performance". [Webopedia - AMD64](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/AMD64.html). There is also an [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) on the x86-64 architeture. But when I installed [Python 3.8.2](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/python-3.8.2-amd64.exe) from the link I get both.

Comment: @MichaelHsi thank you for your advice.  First principle is get the code working first, and then optimize performance as needed.  I agree to stay away from Python's dynamic data types where size cannot be known easily in advance.  For array computations, Numpy is highly optimized for speed if the word size (32 or 64-bit) lines up, since Numpy uses fixed-size numeric array types under the covers.  For dynamic data structures (lists, non-tuples, non-hashmaps, etc.) performance is strongly improved by moving to static-typed languages.